# Random Image PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have 2 database tables. `loppe` containing `username` and `loppeID`, and `billeder` containing `loppeID` and `billedeNavn`.

I would like to have a `div` containing 2 random `billedeNavn` from the same `username`. I have tried some things but I can only figure out how to get 2 `billedeNavn` from the same `loppeID` (username). I'm pretty new to all this. So would me grateful for any help.

```
<?php
    $frontimage = ("SELECT * FROM loppe RIGHT JOIN billeder ON loppe.loppeID=billeder.loppeID WHERE loppe.username = '$username' ORDER BY RAND()");
    $st = $db->prepare($frontimage);
    $st->execute();
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $loppeid = $row['loppeID'];
    $loppe = $loppeid;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM billeder WHERE loppeID = :loppeID order by rand() limit 2";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array("loppeID" => $loppe));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $fname = $row['billedeNavn'];
        echo '<div class="col-xs-6 loppe-pic-outer"><img class="img-responsive loppe-pic" src="loppebilleder/'.$fname.'"></div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this change your
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM billeder WHERE loppeID = :loppeID order by rand() limit 2";`?
to this
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM billeder WHERE loppeID = '.$loppeid.' order by rand() limit 2";`

A good way to figure out what is going on when using php and database is after you create your query do something like
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM billeder WHERE loppeID = '.$loppeid.' order by rand() limit 2";
die($sql);`

So with this you will see what the database is really querying and you can check for in your sql string or query.